# Learnpress FATAL ERROR

Tags: plugins, fatal-error

I got this from an update that has crashed my site:

Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference in /web/htdocs/www.thespectrumofriemannium.com/home/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/learnpress/inc/jwt/includes/class-jwt-public.php on line 309

There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.

HOW CAN I SOLVE IT?

HELP! Please...

Comment: If you can't get an updated version of LearnPress you'll need to show us line 309 of that file, and a few lines either side for context. Please edit them into the question using the 'edit' link at the bottom.

Comment: Here's the solution though: turn a constant you're passing to a function as a reference parameter into a variable. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17279734 Then try and understand what you should be doing with the result it's giving you.

Comment: This specific error was [fixed in LearnPress 4.2.3.4](https://thimpress.com/forums/topic/fatal-error-24/).

Answer (score 1):

As with any plugin error, it's often helpful to delete the plugin files. You can do this on most hosts with FTP or the host's file manager.

Once you've deleted them, you can immediately re-download a fresh copy of the plugin version you want to use - you can try the latest version again or roll back to a known good old version, and upload via FTP or the file manager. Then log in and confirm everything is working. If you used an old version, you can then try updating the plugin again - with your downloaded copy still ready in case you need to roll it back again.

If the problem persists after reinstalling the new version, contact the plugin's support channels directly.